# Can we drop this annoying integral term to restore a Sturm-Liouville problem?

Tags: sturm-liouville-theory

On $[0,1]$, let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be positive and continuous, consider the equation:
$w''+w+\lambda f\cdot (w-\int_0^1 w)=0$($\lambda$ is an eigenvalue) subject to $w(0)=w(1)=0$. If the integral term $\int_0^1w$ is dropped, then this is a classic Sturm-Liouville problem, however, I wonder whether it is possible through some transformations to convert this equation into a classic Sturm-Liouville problem?

Comment: I don't think that's possible (unless $f$ is constant). In operator language, what you have is the equation $Lw=\lambda(1-P)w$, where $L$ is the SL operator $Lw=(1/f)(-w''-w)$ and $Pw=\int w=\langle 1, w\rangle $ is the projection onto constants. It might help to think of the problem this way.

Comment: @Christian Remling, If f=1, a constant, how can we transform?

Comment: If $f=1$, it then the eigenfunctions of $L$ are already orthogonal to $1$, so it appears one can use these (it needs to be looked at a little more carefully, obviously).

Answer (score 1):

You could approach this problem in the usual way, by writing $w(x)$ as a Fourier series, $w(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty w_n \sin(\pi n x)$, and similarly $f$, and then obtaining an infinite set of linear equations for $w_n$,
$$[1-(\pi n)^2 ]w_n +\lambda \sum_{m}f_{n-m}w_m = \frac{2\lambda f_n}{\pi} \sum_{m}\frac{w_{2m-1}}{2m-1}.$$
By truncating this to a finite set you could then find the eigenvalue by demanding that the determinant of the matrix of coefficients vanishes.

Comment: But truncating will not find the ev's exactly (that would mean that the eigenfunctions are trigonometric polynomials, but of course there's no reason for this to happen).

Comment: true, but isn't it generally like that --- for arbitrary function $f$ an exact solution of the eigenvalue problem will not be available and it is approximated by increasing the size of the matrix of coefficients?